# Issue in communicating two pods with each other deployed on two VMs

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-networking

I have deployed two pods on two different Virtual machines. (master and node).

Dockerfile server-side

```
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["python", "model.py"]
```

Server-side python code

```
sock = socket()
sock.bind(('',8080))
```

Client-side python code

```
sock= socket()
sock.connect(('192.168.56.105', 8080))
```

Pod deployment file server

```
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: Pod
 metadata:
 name: server
 labels:
    app: server
 spec:
    containers:
    - name: tensor-keras
      image: tensor-keras:latest
      imagePullPolicy: Never
    ports:
     - containerPort: 8080
```

Pod deployment file server

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: client
  labels:
    app: client
 spec:
   containers:
    - name: tensor
      image: tensor:latest
```

Exposing node port

```
 kubectl expose pod server --type=NodePort
 kubectl expose pod client --port 27017 --type=NodePort
```

kubectl get services

```
NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)           AGE
client         NodePort    10.105.180.221   <none>        27017:31161/TCP   11s
server         NodePort    10.106.22.209    <none>        8080:32284/TCP    35s
kubernetes     ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP           28h
```

I then run the below command for the server and client, it says its waiting for the client to connect and it doesn't gets connected.

```
 kubectl exec -it server  -- /bin/sh
```

But the moment I type the below command Its get connected but I receive an error connection reset by peer.

```
    curl -v localhost:32284
   * Rebuilt URL to: localhost:32284/
   * Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 32284 (#0)
   > GET / HTTP/1.1
   > Host: localhost:32284
   > User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
   > Accept: */*
    predictions_result.npy
    141295744
    Warning: <FILE>" to save to a file.
    * Failed writing body (0 != 13880)
    * stopped the pause stream!
    * Closing connection 0
```

Error

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):File "model.py", line 51, in <module> client.sendall(data)
     ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Thank you very much for helping me with this, help is highly appreciated. I am stuck I have tried port forwarding but it's not working.

Comment: Could you please show what is in the line 51 of the model.py where the error occurs? One of the issues I see is that you're trying to connect from client to server on port 8080, when the service is exposed with a port 32284, could you try to change it?

Comment: Hi @Jakub, thank you very much for your help. I tried to change it to port 32284 but the client is still unable to connect to the server.

Comment: Is ```192.168.56.105``` your kubernetes NodeIP? If so, you will have to connect using port 32284.
But since this is kubernetes environment, i suggest not hardcoding any IP. Instead update the client to use the service name and service port in ```sock.connect(("server",8080))```